# Java Generics extending List

Tags: java, generics

I have the following classes:

```
public interface ServiceSynchronizableEntity {
    ....
}

public class BaseListResponse<T> {
    ....
}

public class BaseSynchronizableListResponse<T extends ServiceSynchronizableEntity> extends BaseListResponse<T> {
    ....
}

public class MySecondClass implements ServiceSynchronizableEntity {
    ....
}

public class MyFirstClass extends BaseSynchronizableListResponse<MySecondClass> {
    ....
}

public class What<S extends BaseSynchronizableListResponse<ServiceSynchronizableEntity>> {

}
```

Then I use it as:

```
What what = new What<MyFirstClass>();
```

When I want to use `MyFirstClass` as a type parameter which extend `BaseListResponse<ServiceSynchronizableEntity>>` it shows me

```
Main.java:26: error: type argument MyFirstClass is not within bounds of type-variable S
    What what = new What<MyFirstClass>();
                         ^
where S is a type-variable: S extends BaseSynchronizableListResponse<ServiceSynchronizableEntity> declared in class What
```

What is wrong?

Edit: One class was missing. Look at: http://ideone.com/D4snKP

Thanks!

Comment: Works here: http://ideone.com/gLlG3b.

Comment: Worked for me too. You got more code to show us what you're doing?

Comment: Works fine i just tested

Comment: Please look at the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I previously posted (now deleted) was similar in that it required a change to the generic signature.

The important change is going from:

```
class What<S extends BaseSynchronizableListResponse<ServiceSynchronizableEntity>> {}
```

to:

```
class What<S extends BaseSynchronizableListResponse<? extends ServiceSynchronizableEntity>> {}
```

See http://ideone.com/wyXvcl for the fixed version